# I am creating a react-native app using expo-cli and I just want to fetch 2 customize env files called .env.staging and .env.production

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Now I am just using process.env.VARIABLE_NAME.
But it is choosing the env file randomly. Sometime it use to show data from .env.staging and sometime from .env.production.
Also When I use to console process.env it use to show {NODE_ENV=development} Which I don't have defined anywhere.

```
REACT_APP_FORCETRACK_URL=https://example.com . It is my .env variable structure.
```

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["transform-inline-environment-variables",
        "module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "envName": "APP_ENV",
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        /*"blocklist": null,
        "allowlist": null,
        "blacklist": null, // DEPRECATED
        "whitelist": null, // DEPRECATED*/
        "safe": false,
        "allowUndefined": true,
        "verbose": false
      }]
    ]
  };
};
```

```
"start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run-script start",
    "start:product": "env-cmd -f .env.product npm run-script start"
```

These are my scripts to decide which file I have to run on runtime

This is my babel.config.js file.
Can you please find the reason why it is doing this.
If it has any unsupportive nature of module Can you provide any alternative to access environment variable

Comment: If any other file you have need from project just comment it I will share it.